# StrongLoop: ACL for Subtable

Tags: javascript, node.js, acl, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have two tables `A` and `B`. `A` hasOne `B`, `B` belongsTo `A`.

Now I have the following ACL in `B`:

```
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "DENY",
  "accessType": "*"
}
```

When I make a request to `localhost/api/B/{id}` I receive 401.

When I make a request to `localhost/api/A/{id}/B` I receive the data.

How can I fix this? Both should get a 401 error. Is there a solution where I don't have to touch `A.json`?

I could make an acl fix in `A` but I think, this would be ugly.

Found something in the [StrongLoop Doc](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Accessing+related+models) this means I have to define ACLs in `A` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current version of loopback that is the case. You can find different references in github issues https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/960
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control/issues/41

The document you linked actually has an explicit warning for the opposite problem, getting related instances when connected through User.

> If a model has a DENY ALL permission (for example a built-in model
>   such as the User model), but related models have no ACLs, the related
>   models will still not be accessible through the User model. So, for
>   example, even if the books model's default ACL is ALLOW $authenticated
>   for GET /books, the route GET /user/{id}/books default will still be
>   DENY ALL.

It seems you also need to be explicit in granting or not access, doing so for each generated method you wish to modify. An example for user having a hasAndBelongsToMany:

```
{
  "accessType": "READ",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$authenticated",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__get__skills"
},
{
  "accessType": "WRITE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__link__skills"
},
{
  "accessType": "WRITE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__unlink__skills"
}
```

I remember seeing that a new way of handling ACL affecting related models would be implemented in version 3 but I can't find the reference again.

Comment: Ok it works like you said. I'm looking forward to the next StrongLoop version :)

Comment: I think the correct json would be without `accessType`. There is no need for that because you define it in `property`. And for my question it would be `__get__b` instead of `__get__skills`. Thank you :)